# Backspace not working in contentEditable (Froala) after I insert and remove a node [for the purpose of finding the caret]

Tags: javascript, keydown, froala

In the onKeyDown of a backspace keypress, I am trying to get the caret position in the Froala WYSIWYG editor. It is a contentEditable div that exists in an iframe. However, this process seems to be preventing backspace from working correctly. If I do not insert the `target` into the selection, backspace works fine, but then I don't have any idea where my caret is.

**What is confusing to me is why this would happen at all, shouldn't the new character be added and removed during the execution of this code entirely such that it was as if it was never there and not interfere with backspace?**

```
function getCaretPositionOnBackspace(){
    function getIframe(){
            var iframe = $wnd.document.getElementsByClassName('fr-iframe')[0]; //my framework demands that I write $wnd.document instead of document
            return iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
        }

        var iframe = getIframe();
        var target = iframe.createTextNode("\u0001");
        iframe.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).insertNode(target);
        var position = editor.$el[0].innerHTML.indexOf("\u0001"); //editor.$el[0] is the contentEditable itself for people unfamiliar with Froala
        target.parentNode.removeChild(target);
        return position;

}
```

Here is a codepen that demonstrates part of the problem: https://codepen.io/glenpierce/pen/QOdYBz
In this example, try typing several characters in a row, then you'll be able to successfully delete one character, then the next backspace will instead move the caret to the beginning of the text, then I haven't been able to backspace over a character afterwards. You may then comment out the call to `getCaretPositionWithinInnerHtml(editor.$el)` and you'll see that backspace works fine again.

My attempts to reproduce this have inconsistent results, it seems that it's important to have the caret somewhere before the end of the text your entering.